# Type name showing up in WPF drop-down list

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm binding a `List<SelectItem>` to a `ComboBox` using MVVM.  The combobox has the right value and looks fine.  However, when I click on the down button to see all the options in the combobox, I get a list of 10 items that each read `MyNamespace.SelectItem`.  If I select #2, the value in the combobox then reads `2`.

Here's the code for `SelectItem`:

```
public class SelectItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyListValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And here's where I queue up a list of `SelectItems`:

```
        MyList= new List<SelectItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var page = new SelectItem()
            {
                Display = i.ToString(),
                Value = i.ToString()
            };
            MyList.Add(page);
            if (i == 1)
                MyListValue = page;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for any typo.

With following code:

```
public class SelectItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

public class SelectItemViewModel
{
    public List<SelectItem> MyList { get; set; }
    public SelectItem MyListValue { get; set; }

    public SelectItemViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<SelectItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var page = new SelectItem()
            {
                Display = i.ToString(),
                Value = i.ToString()
            };
            MyList.Add(page);
            if (i == 1)
                MyListValue = page;
        }
    }
}
```

Initialization:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new SelectItemViewModel();
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Display"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyListValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I was able to see numbers in the `ComboBox`. No type names.

Comment: yea it worked yesterday and then after i played around a bit with deployment stuff i started noticing this odd behavior.

Comment: You weren't playing around with the style by an chance?

Comment: Quinn351 - I did play around with the style.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Wow!  I removed the <ResourceDictionary Source="WhistlerBlue.xaml" /> from my App.xaml (got that file from wpf.codeplex.com's wpf themes) and low and behold, it worked again!  WTF?

Comment: That's strange!! Could be some overriding in that `Style`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use theme in your application and has something like

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="WhistlerBlue.xaml" />
```

in your App.xaml, try to overwrite the item style of the combo box by adding

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```